# RPC_E_SERVERFAULT when automating Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, ms-word

I'm creating word documents from templates (.dot) via `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. The code below works on some templates but not on others: where it doesn't work it throws an `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT` exception. What is this about, what can be the cause, and how could I fix it? (The exception occurs on the second line.)

```
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref newTemplate, ref docType, ref isVisible);
wordApp.Visible = false;
wordDoc.Activate();
```

Comment: It would be useful to know whether you do this in an interactive environment or on a server. A typical problem with Word automation is that the application is not responding due to popup message boxes, or - on a server - that another process has closed the Word instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will hate me and downvote me probably but in all my .NET work experience working with the COM Interop is a PIA (pun intended / PIA also means Primary Interop Assemblies).

Usually the performance is so bad that makes the whole thing unacceptable. So we resorted to buying a 3rd party, managed, non-Office-dependent library that does the same thing WAY faster.